# TableView Reload rows Limitation

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, tableview

I want to reload just 3 first index of array
what should i do ?
Or how shuold i use these ?

```
var visibleCells: [UITableViewCell] { get }
var indexPathsForVisibleRows: [IndexPath]? { get }
```

Comment: Does your first 3 cells would be available all time?

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you have tried so far.

Comment: So you should give more information about what you want

Comment: @VIP-DEV
yes, the response is more than 400 cells, but i want to reload just 3 first

Comment: @Xcoder
lets say in another way , i have a response that fill 100 cells, but i want to load just 3 first cells

Comment: @SeyedSamadGholamzadeh
i said it in top

Comment: The best option in such a case is to predefine the first three cell and just modify its content. So we don't need to unnecessary call for reload

Answer (score 1):

You should use

> func reloadRows(at indexPaths: [IndexPath], with animation:
>   UITableViewRowAnimation)
>   for example

```
let set = [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)]
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: set, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: Array(indexPathsForVisibleRows[0..<3]), with: .automatic)
```